# Nodejs asymmetrical buffer <-> string conversion

Tags: node.js, buffer

In nodejs I had naively expected the following to always output `true`:

```
let buff = Buffer.allocUnsafe(20); // Essentially random contents
let str = buff.toString('utf8');
let decode = Buffer.from(str, 'utf8');
console.log(0 === buff.compare(decode));
```

Given a Buffer `buff`, how can I detect ahead of time whether `buff` will be exactly equal to `Buffer.from(buff.toString('utf8'), 'utf8')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be probably be fine by just testing that the input buffer contains valid UTF-8 data:

```js
try {
    new TextDecoder('utf-8', { fatal: true }).decode(buff);
    console.log(true);
} catch {
    console.log(false);
}
```

But I wouldn't swear on Node being 100% consistent in the handling of invalid UTF-8 data when converting from string to buffer. If you want to be safe, you'll have to stick to buffer comparison. You could make the process of encoding/decoding a little more efficient by using [`transcode`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffertranscodesource-fromenc-toenc), which does not require creating a temporary string.

```js
import { transcode } from 'buffer';

let buff = Buffer.allocUnsafe(20);
let decode = transcode(buff, 'utf8', 'utf8');
console.log(0 === buff.compare(decode));
```

If you're interested how `TextDecoder` determines if a buffer represents a valid utf8 string, the rigorous definition of this procedure can be found [here](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#the-encoding).